# Cannot resolve method "getMapAsync"

Tags: android, google-maps, android-studio

Excuse me for any grammatical errors.
I followed a tutorial to view the google map in a fragment, but something has gone wrong.

this is my file .java that is hooked with the fragment:

```
public class MapFragment extends Fragment implements OnMapReadyCallback{
@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_map, container, false);

}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

    MapFragment fragment = (MapFragment)getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    fragment.getMapAsync(this); //Here i get the error
}

@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {

}
```

}

This is the layout fragment:

```
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    class="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"></fragment>
```

What did I do wrong?

Thank you!

Comment: What exactly has gone wrong?

Comment: Now, when I open the map, in the console I see this error: http://pastebin.com/RZehk7XC

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to use `SupportMapFragment` rather than `MapFragment`
in XML

```
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"></fragment>
```

in Fragment

```
SupportMapFragment fragment = (SupportMapFragment)getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
fragment.getMapAsync(this);
```

Comment: `getChildFragmentManager()` made the trick to me. I forgot the fact that a `Fragment` inside a `Fragment` (and declared in the xml) uses `childFragmentManager` and not `supportFragmentManager`.