# Cannot find symbol method getMapAsync()

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to create app that include google maps in there, but I'm stuck at this error

`error: cannot find symbol method getMapAsync(SubActivity)`

I've trying something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42166972/cannot-resolve-method-getmapasync), but it doesn't work.
When I run apps it always getting that error. Can someone help please, I'm new at android studio programming.
Here's some of my code.

**build.gradle**

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
    compile project(':google-play-services_lib')
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:10.2.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:8.3.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:8.3.0'
}
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<meta-data
     android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
     android:value="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" />

<meta-data
     android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
     android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```

**activity_sub.xml**

```
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
            android:id="@+id/map"
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            tools:context=".MapsActivity" />
```

**SubActivity.java**

```
public class SubActivity extends AppCompatActivity
        implements OnItemSelectedListener, OnClickListener, OnMapReadyCallback {
        private GoogleMap gMap;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            .
            .
            .
            SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
            mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
        }

        @Override
        public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
            if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                // TODO: Consider calling
                //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
                // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
                //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
                //                                          int[] grantResults)
                // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
                // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
                return;
            }
            googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
            googleMap.setPadding(0, 0, 0, 90);

            gMap = googleMap;

            // Add a marker in Sydney, Australia, and move the camera.
            LatLng sydney = new LatLng(-34, 151);
            gMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(sydney).title("Marker in Sydney"));
            gMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(sydney));
        }
}
```

Comment: I don't use any Play Services much these days, but those versions seem rather old. I think the latest Maps was version 16, or thereabouts. Aren't some of those lines in your `dependencies` highlighted? Which version of Android Studio are you running?

Comment: @MikeM.i'm using Android Studio 3.4.1

Comment: Well, I would imagine that it's still indicating that there are newer versions available for those `dependencies`. Hover your mouse over `compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:8.3.0'`, and see what it suggests in the pop-up. I'd think that it's complaining about `compile`, too.

Comment: It says `cannot find symbol method getMapAsync(SubActivity).` The `SubActivity` is a class that you created and Google Maps knows nothing about it. The `getMapAsync()` expects an implementation of the `OnMapReadyCallback` interface [just as the documentation says](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/MapFragment#getMapAsync(com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback)) and your `SubActivity` doesn't implement that interface. That could be the problem, but I'm not sure, so I'll just comment for now. (Questions shouldn't be answered in comments.)

Comment: @MarkusKauppinen my SubActivity class already implement OnMapReadyCallback there

Comment: Heh, true. I need to wake up. :)

Comment: @MikeM. no complaining about that compile

Comment: Well, I'd advise you to upgrade Android Studio to the latest version, if you can. Anyway, I'm fairly certain that the current specific issue is that your Maps version is too old. I can't pin down exactly which version introduced the `getMapAsync()` method, but if your IDE accepts `getMap()` instead, then that's the only issue; i.e., you need to use a newer version.

Comment: @MikeM. now I'm using ```com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:16.1.0``` and getting error ```java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.```. I'm already try using ```Theme.AppCompat``` in my ```style.xml``` but still got that error.

Comment: Well, that's not a Maps problem, so hopefully that's taken care of, at least. That new Exception can happen due to a few different things. If you're absolutely certain that you're using `Theme.AppCompat` on all of the necessary Activities, then the next most common cause is using the wrong `Context` in your code somewhere; e.g., using `getApplicationContext()` when you should be using the `Activity` as the `Context`. I can't really be specific without the stack trace, and a [mcve].